# Copy characters in array with snprintf

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I am trying to print "hello" in an array but diagonally using the standard function **snprintf**:

This is the code that I did but does not work may indicate that I'm doing wrong :

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, u;
    char buff[26] = {0};
    char abc[] = "hello";

    for (i = 0, u = 0; i < 6; i++, u++)
        snprintf(buff+u, 6, "%*c\n%c", u, abc[i],  i);
    puts(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be :

```
h
 e
  l
   l
    o
```

Thank you

Comment: Step through with a debugger and watch `buff` and you'd see the problem immediately.

Comment: What is the problem with "buff"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change to

```
for (i = 0, u = 0; i < 5; i++)
    u += snprintf(buff+u, sizeof(buff) - u, "%*c\n", i+1, abc[i]);
```

Comment: The second parameter for length doesn't do what it should.

Comment: My first comment was ambiguous; your code can go out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this using `snprintf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    char buf[40];
    char abc[] = "hello";

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 5; ++i, j += i+1) {
        snprintf(buf+j, i+3, "%*c\n", i+1, abc[i]);
    }
    printf("%s",buf);

    return 0;
}
```

`j` tracks position where in each iteration `snprintf` should write to `buf`. `i+3` is the amount of chars written to buf, including newline char and null terminating char. In each iteration of loop the previous null terminating char gets overwritten - that's because of `j += i+1`. 
Output is:

```
h
 e
  l
   l
    o
```

Comment: As I can implement this into a recursive function